# How to get any property descriptor?

Tags: javascript

How to get a property descriptor of a property of an object if it is not it's [own property descriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor), because it has been inherited?

Comment: You'd need to look up the object's prototype with `Object.getPrototypeOf()` and then check that

Answer (score 0):

Look in the prototype chain:

```js
Object.findPropertyDescriptor = function(obj, name){
  let descriptor;
  do {
    (descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, name)) || (obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));
  } while (!descriptor && obj);
  return descriptor;
};

class Base {
  get test(){
    return true;
  }
}

class Child extends Base{
  
}

const child = new Child;

console.log(Object.findPropertyDescriptor(child, 'test'));
console.log(Object.findPropertyDescriptor(child, 'missing'));
```